# how to make button Move to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I make `Button`s to move to Another `ViewController` ?

Can anyone help me please and here is my code .
I tried with `button1: UIButton!` but I Got error

```
class Interest1
{
    var title = ""
    var description = ""
    var featuredImage: UIImage!
    var button1: UIButton!
    var button2: UIButton!
    var button3: UIButton!
    var button4: UIButton!

    init(title: String, featuredImage: UIImage!, button1: UIButton!)
    {
        self.title = title
        self.featuredImage = featuredImage
    }

    static func createInterest() -> [Interest1]
    {
        return [
           Interest1(title: "One", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"001.png")!, button1: UIButton), // I got error Here i don't know why
            Interest1(title: "Two", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"002.png")!),
            Interest1(title: "Three", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"003.png")!),
            Interest1(title: "Four", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"004.png")!),
        ]    
    }
}
```

code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return interests3.count //error
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "1", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! interestCollectionViewCell
    cell.interest2 = self.interests3[indexPath.item] //error
    return cell
}
```

the error is `use of unresolved identifier 'interests3'`

Comment: do you want them to be displayed on another view controller?

Comment: i have 4 images liks ScrollView and i want button 1 for image 1 ...etc like this and whan i click on button1 i want it move to another viewcontroller

Comment: button1 for view1 , and button2 for view2 , already i have 4 view

Comment: @VladHatko any help

Comment: I can't understand what do you want :)

Comment: @VladHatko i want to use button here ` Interest1(title: "One", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"001.png")!, button1: UIButton),` but i got error this view i make it like game ludo star but the button dosen't work

Answer (score 0):

Remove type annotation as below code -

```
static func createInterest() -> [Interest1]
    {

        return [
           Interest1(title: "One", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"001.png")!, button1: button1), // Removed from here
            Interest1(title: "Two", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"002.png")!),
            Interest1(title: "Three", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"003.png")!),
            Interest1(title: "Four", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"004.png")!),

        ]

    }
```

And change `init` function like this -

```
init(title: String, featuredImage: UIImage, button1: UIButton)
    {
        self.title = title
        self.featuredImage = featuredImage
    }
```

And add `static` like this -

```
static var button1: UIButton!
static var button2: UIButton!
static var button3: UIButton!
static var button4: UIButton!
```

Here is full code -

```
class Interest1
{
    var title = ""
    var description = ""
    var featuredImage: UIImage!
    static var button1: UIButton!
    static var button2: UIButton!
    static var button3: UIButton!
    static var button4: UIButton!

    subscript(index:Int)->Int
    {
        return 5
    }

    init(title: String, featuredImage: UIImage, button: UIButton)
    {
        self.title = title
        self.featuredImage = featuredImage


    }

    static func createInterest() -> [Interest1]
    {
        return [
            Interest1(title: "One", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"001.png")!, button: button1),
            Interest1(title: "Two", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"002.png")!, button: button2),
            Interest1(title: "Three", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"003.png")!, button: button3),
            Interest1(title: "Four", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"004.png")!, button: button4),
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: i got this error `instance member 'button1' cannot be used on type 'interest1'`

Comment: didn't work i think cuse the button not in the same class

Comment: if i remove `static` i will get error here `var interests3 = Interest1.createInterest()` i import func to another class

Comment: when i add `static var button4: UIButton!` i got error to delete `static` from `static var button4: UIButton!`

Comment: sorry bro but i hate swift , i add some code i got error when i use your code

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems regarding your code. It will be nice to fix them.

You don't have to name your parameters like button1 - button is more suitable here, so your constructor can be like

```
init(title: String, featuredImage: UIImage!, button: UIButton!)
```

Force unwrapping here is not a nice way to go. Better to remove it, so constructor be:

```
init(title: String, featuredImage: UIImage, button: UIButton)
```

Now, inside of constructor you don't use your button at all. I think you wanted to set it, like

```
init(title: String, featuredImage: UIImage, button: UIButton)
    {
        self.title = title
        self.featuredImage = featuredImage
        self.button = button
    }
```

Finally, in your created objects you're using not existing constructor here:

```
Interest1(title: "Two", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"002.png")!)
```

You have to provide buttons as well. So, probably you wanted to do something like this:

```
   static func createInterest() -> [Interest1]
        {
            return [
               Interest1(title: "One", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"001.png")!, button: someFirstButton), // I got error Here i don't know why
                Interest1(title: "Two", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"002.png")!, button: someSecondButton),
                Interest1(title: "Three", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"003.png")!, button: someThirdButton)
            ]    
        }
```

Note, that you probably want to provide your buttons inside, instead someFirstButton, someSecondButton, someThirdButton

Good luck

Comment: thank you , but my problem is here `someFirstButton, someSecondButton, someThirdButton` what can i write here cuse the buttons not in the same class it's from another class

Comment: when i move to anothrt class i got error in `init` the error is `initializers may only be declared within a type`

Comment: you can move only *createInterest* func there, without init

Comment: i hate swift , still not working i made this code from youtube but i want to add button and i can't